# How to I make a custom scalar type in graphql pothos?

Tags: typescript, graphql, scalar, typegraphql

#### I am trying to make a custom scalar type called *JSONObject* that will be applied to an input parameter that will accept an array of JSON-formatted documents and I cannot get it to work.

The type is getting to the graphiql development interface, but the type must not accurately describe what I think it is describing because it says that it expects the field to be the type called *JSONObject* I've defined. I have even tried making a type that will accept anything that isn't null or undefined and it still behaves the same way.

## Code:

#### The scalar input and output

*This does not change for any of the examples*

```js
    Scalars: {
        Date: {
            Input: Date;
            Output: Date;
        };
        mongoId: {
            Input: ObjectId;
            Output: ObjectId;
        };
        JSONObject: {
            Input: any;
            Output: any;
        };
        objectIdOrEmpty: {
            Input: ObjectId | Empty;
            Output: ObjectId | Empty;
        };
    };
```

#### Using pre made scalars

```js
// implementing a premade graphql scalar

builder.addScalarType('mongoId', ObjectIDResolver, {});
builder.addScalarType('Date', DateTimeResolver, {});
// the new one that didn't work
builder.addScalarType('JSONObject', JSONResolver, {});
```

#### Attempt #1 at custom scalar:

```js
builder.scalarType('JSONObject', {
    serialize: (value) => {
        let o = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value));
        if (o && o._id) {
            return o
        } else {
            throw new Error('Not a valid JSON Object');
        }
    },

    parseValue: (value) => {
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            return value
        } else
            throw new Error('Invalid value for Json Type Custom Scalar');
    }
})
```

#### Attempt to have it accept any value:

```js
builder.scalarType('JSONObject', {
    serialize: (value) => {
        return value;
    },

    parseValue: (value: any) => {
        if (value !== null && value !== undefined) {
            return value;
        }
        else {
            throw new Error('JSONObject cannot represent non-object value: ' + value);
        }
    }
})
```

To reiterate I want to make a sclar type for an argument input in a mutation that will accept an object like this:

```js
[{ 
"weight": 0, 
"spotsAvailable": [{ "userId": "empty", "name": "empty" }, { "userId": "67fd6sdhfds7yf87", "name": "John" }]
 }, { 
"weight": 0, 
"spotsAvailable": [{ "userId": "empty", "name": "empty" }, { "userId": "67fd6sdhfds7yf87", "name": "John" }] }]
```

**here is the mutation**

```js
        createEvent: t.fieldWithInput({
            input: {
                longitude: t.input.float({ required: true }),
                latitude: t.input.float({ required: true }),
                name: t.input.string({ required: true }),
                date: t.input.field({ type: 'Date', required: true }),
                description: t.input.string({ required: true }),
                cost: t.input.string(),
                link: t.input.string(),
                // 
                // We need to get weights working here
                // 
                weights: t.input.field({ type: 'JSONObject' })
            },
            type: EventType,
            resolve: (_, { input: { longitude, latitude, name, date, description, cost, link, weights, }, argWeights }, context) => {

                const location: Location = {
                    type: 'Point',
                    coordinates: [longitude, latitude]
                }

                let anObject = {
                    createdBy: context.currentUser._id as ObjectId, location, name, date, description,
                    cost: cost ? cost : undefined, link: link ? link : undefined, weights: argWeights ? argWeights : undefined,
                }

                return dbMutations.createEvent(anObject);
            }
        }),
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem is you need to create an arg type if you are defining an argument input and not a regular field type. What I was doing for the custom scalar type wasn't wrong, but it was defining an argument, not a scalar.

So I don't have the best solution for defining JSON type, but I can give an example of how the custom scalar works

### Scalar:

```js
// this is where you can modify the data before passing it to the actual parse function

builder.scalarType('JSONObject', {
    serialize: (value) => {
        return value;
    },

// this is where you return the value or an error if it doesn't meet your requirements 

    parseValue: (value: any) => {
        if (value !== null && value !== undefined) {
            return value;
        }
        else {
            throw new Error('JSONObject cannot represent non-object value: ' + value);
        }
    }
})
```

#### You must also define Scalars in the builder properties

```js
    Scalars: {
        Date: {
            Input: Date;
            Output: Date;
        };
        mongoId: {
            Input: ObjectId;
            Output: ObjectId;
        };
        JSONObject: {
            Input: any;
            Output: any;
        };
    };
// I gave extra examples for clarity
```